# I want to use the ItemName and a timestamp in filenamn when copy to sink

Tags: azure

I have metadata_output that looks like this @activity('GetMetadata1').output.itemName
and now that looks like this @pipeline().TriggerTime I can use either of these @dataSet().now() to specify the filename or
specify the metadata_output instead like this @dataset().metadata_output as the filename

But I want to combine these because I want to have a timestamp and a filename like this
@dataSet().now() + @activity('GetMetadata1').output.itemName I can't make it to work

Many thanks in advance
Tony Johansson

Answer (score 0):

- You can use `concat` function to build the file name as required. The following is the demonstration of the same. Let's say you have created 2 parameters in the sink dataset as shown in the below image:

[image]

- Now using the dynamic content for filename in the sink as `@concat(dataset().metadata_output,dataset().now,'.csv')`, I was able to generate filename as required (my destination file format is csv, so added it as well).

[image]

- Pass the values for these parameters from the sink dataset as you are doing it.

[image]

- The following is how the filename would be generated:

[image]